# Grub Menu Does Not Match Kernels

Tags: centos, boot, grub

My grub menu does not match my current kernels. And I am unable to boot into most recently kernel installed in /boot

I see that grub.cfg appears both in /boot/grub2 and /boot/efi/EFI/centos

And it is the EFI one that it's using for the menu, but the recent yum updated the /boot/grub2 one.

My system is BIOS not EFI; I do have /sys/firmware/efi, but the whole /sys directory was only recently created (computer is 4 years old).

What's going on? And how to fix?

Comment: Has the system recently received any firmware updates? They might have caused the change from a previous BIOS-style boot preference to a current UEFI one. Remember that UEFI has been a Microsoft certification requirement since the release of Windows 8 in year 2012, and the /sys filesystem has existed since the early 2.6.x kernel versions: the first mentions of it in kernel.org Git version history are from 2005, and that's probably just because the history accessible with Git does not reach further back than that.